# How to pass parameter in onclick function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Inside javaScript function i code like this...

```
function myFunction(){
.....

completeTreeView = completeTreeView + 
   "<li><input type='checkbox' id=" + name +
   " /><label for='item-0' onclick='myclicktest(\'' + result.name +
   '\')' >" + Address + "</label>";

.......
}

function myclicktest(name){
            alert(name);
}
```

How to pass and get the result.name

Comment: 1) Don't append HTML as string, use [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/document.createElement) 2) don't use inline event handlers, use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) instead. 3) the codehighlighting from SO already gives you the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed it... i used as below.

```
completeTreeView = completeTreeView + "<li><input type='checkbox' id="+ name+" /><label for='item-0' onclick='myclicktest(\"" +  Address + "\")' >"+ Address+"</label>";
```

Thanks to all for providing me clue to fix it.

Comment: Did none of the other answer solve your problem so that you have to post a different one?

Comment: yes @Christoph.. i got syntax error of all the above answer in my way of approach....

Comment: There are three other answers telling you exactly this! There is no need for this absolutely redundant answer. Instead you could give credits to one of those answers by accepting them as correct answer...

Comment: None of the answer helped me, but gave me clue to fix the issue. you can check my answer. But i provide +1(upvote) to them for providing me clue @Christoph.

Comment: I don't see any difference from your answer to the others other than the different variable names which comes from you changing your question after they wrote their answers.

Comment: you can able to see different in line...   'myclicktest(\"" + nodeNameIpAddress + "\")'

Answer (score 1):

```
completeTreeView = completeTreeView + '<li><input type="checkbox" id="' + parent.node.name + '" /><label for="item-0" onclick="myclicktest(\'' + result.name + '\')">' + nodeNameIpAddress + '</label>';
```

Html attributes use " and it is better to use ' for javascript strings

So if you cannot reverse :

```
completeTreeView = completeTreeView + "<li><input type='checkbox' id=" + parent.node.name + " /><label for='item-0' onclick=\"myclicktest('" + result.name + "')\" >" + nodeNameIpAddress + "</label>";
```

Comment: but in my case i need to use ' instead of "

Comment: i made it reverse... use " instead of '

Comment: given +1 for providing clue to fix my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
function myFunction() {
  // .....

  completeTreeView = completeTreeView + "<li><input type='checkbox' id=" + parent.node.name + " /><label for='item-0' onclick='myclicktest(\'" + result.name + "\')' >" + nodeNameIpAddress + "</label>";

  // .......
}

function myclicktest(name) {
  alert(name);
}
```

Just notice the quotes before and after `result.name`.

Answer (score 1):

The approach seems to be correct.

Please check the single quote or double quote issues in javascript.

You can find the javascript issue in console if you are using firebug in firefox.

You can also check the "result.name" value in an alert to confirm that you are getting the value.

Thanks

Comment: given +1 for providing clue(quote). which help me to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<label><input type='checkbox' onclick='myclicktest(this);'>Checkbox</label>

function myclicktest(cb)
{
  display("Clicked, new value = " + cb.checked);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is define the parameter when you bind the event.

```
function bindEvToThing(str, el)
{
    var name = str
    el.onmouseup = function()
    {
        alert(name)
    }
}
```